# filters in Java Servlet not working properly?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web.xml, servlet-filters

I am a beginner in using Java Servlets. I am having some issues with my servlets.
my filters are not being applied.

Here is my web.xml:

```
<web-app>
<display-name>CP130 Assignment 8</display-name>
<filter>
    <description>Filter using XSLT to format servlet response</description>
    <display-name>CP130QuoteTransformFilter</display-name>
    <filter-name>QuoteResponseFormatter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>edu.uw.rgm.web.QuoteTransformFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <description>HTML transform</description>
        <param-name>html-transform</param-name>
        <param-value>xslt/quote2html.xslt</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <description>JSON transform</description>
        <param-name>json-transform</param-name>
        <param-value>xslt/quote2json.xslt</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <description>Plain transform</description>
        <param-name>plain-transform</param-name>
        <param-value>xslt/quote2plain.xslt</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<servlet>
    <description>Servlet obtaining stock quote from Yahoo Financial Services</description>
    <display-name>CP130QuoteServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>StockQuoteJsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>edu.uw.rgm.web.YahooStockQuoteServlet</servlet-class>
    <jsp-file>/Quote.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>StockQuoteJsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Quote.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>QuoteResponseFormatter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>StockQuoteJsp</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>QuoteResponseFormatter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/Quote.jsp</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

I have placed some `println` statements in the filters I apply for the response. when I run my main app in the console, I see that no print is generated. It probably indicates that my response is not passing through filters. I triple checked the filter names and filter-class and url-patterns and there is no typo in it.

I get the following error:

```
[WARNING] 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:297)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://localhost:8080/StockQuote/Quote.jsp?symbol=GOOG&rstype=json
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1624)
    at app.QuoteApp.exec(QuoteApp.java:73)
    at app.QuoteApp.main(QuoteApp.java:100)
    ... 6 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.820s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Jun 17 12:49:02 PDT 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/245M
```

Does the order of elements in web.xml matter?

why is my filter not applied in response?

Thanks

### **EDIT:**

Here is the latest version of `web.xml` that I tried. I just moved `filter` element below `servlet` element in `web.xml`
I do not any error this time. but again the filter is not applied.

`web.xml`:

```
<web-app>
    <display-name>CP130 Assignment 8</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <description>Servlet obtaining stock quote from Yahoo Financial Services</description>
        <display-name>CP130QuoteServlet</display-name>
        <servlet-name>StockQuoteJsp</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/Quote.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>StockQuoteJsp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>edu.uw.rgm.web.YahooStockQuoteServlet</servlet-class>
        <url-pattern>/Quote.jsp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <filter>
        <description>Filter using XSLT to format servlet response</description>
        <display-name>CP130QuoteTransformFilter</display-name>
        <filter-name>QuoteResponseFormatter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>edu.uw.rgm.web.QuoteTransformFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <description>HTML transform</description>
            <param-name>html-transform</param-name>
            <param-value>xslt/quote2html.xslt</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <description>JSON transform</description>
            <param-name>json-transform</param-name>
            <param-value>xslt/quote2json.xslt</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <description>Plain transform</description>
            <param-name>plain-transform</param-name>
            <param-value>xslt/quote2plain.xslt</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>QuoteResponseFormatter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>StockQuoteJsp</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>QuoteResponseFormatter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/Quote.jsp</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: I have a very basic question: when the user enters your URL (like this in the log: http:// localhost:8080/StockQuote/Quote.jsp?symbol=GOOG&rstype=json) which one do you want to answer it: the JSP page or the servlet?

Answer (score 1):

As per the [web-app_2_3.dtd](http://dtddoc.sourceforge.net/example/j2ee131/web-app_2_3.dtd.org.html)

```
<!ELEMENT servlet (icon?, servlet-name, display-name?, description?,
(servlet-class|jsp-file), init-param*, load-on-startup?, run-as?, security-role-ref*)>
```

Use either `<jsp-file>` or `<servlet-class>` under `<servlet>`. Since JSP is finally converted to Servlet class so you can't use both at a time.

```
<servlet>
    <description>Servlet obtaining stock quote from Yahoo Financial Services</description>
    <display-name>CP130QuoteServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>StockQuoteJsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>edu.uw.rgm.web.YahooStockQuoteServlet</servlet-class>
    <jsp-file>/Quote.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
```

As per the exception `FileNotFoundException`, Is `Quote.jsp` placed directly under the webapp/webcontent folder?

---

#### EDIT

*For a specific URL pattern either you can redirect it to a JSP page or a Servlet class.*

In below case the Servlet will be called whenever `Quote.jsp` is passed in the URL.

```
<servlet>
    <description>Servlet obtaining stock quote from Yahoo Financial Services</description>
    <display-name>CP130QuoteServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>StockQuoteJsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>edu.uw.rgm.web.YahooStockQuoteServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>StockQuoteJsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Quote.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: then how do I connect my servlet with the jsp. i,e how do I specify which servletclass to be called when I access a particular jsp

Comment: yes it is placed directly `webapps/StockQuote/Quote.jsp`

Comment: Just remove `<servlet-class>` if you want to point it to JSP. If you want to call the servlet class if a specific JSP is called then define it in `servlet-mapping` as `url-pattern`

Comment: No it's incorrect. Just remove `<jsp-file>` because you have a mapping already defined in your web.xml file. But now in this case the original JSP will never be called. Servlet is solely responsible for the HTML content generation or any further processing. You can redirect it to JSP from the Servlet if needed.

Comment: I have inserted servlet mapping in the edit section below. please see the bottom of the post and confirm if that is correct

Comment: I am not clear what you want to achieve? Please have a look at my edited post.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried what you suggested before. But I face a weird problem of welcome page not loading. I have posted that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24291849/welcome-page-not-loading-properly-with-filters-in-web-xml-in-java-servlets please take a look. Thanks

Comment: What is the flow of your application if `Quote.jsp` passed in the URL?

Comment: Do you have `Quote.jsp` in your project? If yes then what you want when it's passed in the URL because as per the `url-pattern` defined in `web.xml` it will mapped for `filter` as well as `Servlet`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55866/discussion-between-brain-storm-and-braj).